# How to pass values dynamic values in ssis stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

I have a question about SSIS: please tell me how to load a stored procedure result into a table using a SSIS package.

I want to load the result of a stored procedure into another table.

I have tried in `ExecuteSQL` task like this:

```
insert into abctest123([lat], [long], [city], [state], [add])

    EXEC GECODE_U 
         @Address = '1234 N. Main Street',
         @City = 'Santa Ana',
         @State = 'CA'
```

This query is working fine using `Execute SQL Task` in SSIS.

The address and city and state values will change frequently. Therefore, I created variables to pass the values dynamicaly to SSIS.

I tried like this - I created 3 variables address, city, state:

```
insert into abctest123([lat], [long], [city], [state], [add])
    EXEC GECODE_U  ? , ? ,?
```

After that in Execute SQL using parameter mapping, I assign the 3 variables created, but I get this error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "insert into abctest123( [lat]
>         ,[long] ..."
>   failed with the following error:
>   Incorrect syntax near '@P2'.
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Please tell me how to pass dynamic values and solve this issue in SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add them to the option parameter mapping inside your Execute SQL Task.

You can do it like this:

Create table first:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testtest](
[Adress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[State] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then create your SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NAME
 @Adress nvarchar(50), @City nvarchar(50), @State nvarchar(50) AS

BEGIN

insert into dbo.Testtest (Adress,City,[State])
select @Adress,@City,@State 
END
```

Then make your SSIS-Package with an Execute SQL Task, and create your 3 variables called Adress,City,State.
Next inside your Execute SQL Task you do like this:

[image]

When you have done that, you should be able to write your expression inside the SQL Statement, like this:

[image]

Then you should get this result inside your table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Execute SQL Task Editor - set the Result Set property as Full Result Set
Then,
In the Result Set Tab - accordingly assign the result to one/multiple variables

Comment: its not working.its giving [Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".

Comment: Resultset is only used to fill out variables or objects.